# CSS: Is it possible for a td to infer style from its header or vice versa?

Tags: html, css

I am formatting my tables, and some of them have hyperlinks in the right hand column which I want right aligned. Is there a way from css to infer that the column has links in it, and right align the whole column, including the header?

Alternatively, is there a way to apply a class to just the header and have it affect the alignment of all of the columns underneath it?

I recognize that I can apply a style to the individual th and td elements, but I was hoping for something a little more elegant.

EDIT: There is only one table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Some Column</th>
      <th>actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some data</td>
      <td><a href="some/url">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

I am asking if I can apply a style to the  element for the actions and write CSS which will cause all of the  elements in that column be style a particular way.

Comment: CSS doesn't infer; it follows rules. Post your code please.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  I get nervous when I hear "multiple tables" when what is described sounds like navigation.

Comment: @fnostro I never said 'multiple tables' so I'm not sure what you mean. I'm simply putting a link in the last cell. For example, there might be a list of items and an Edit link at the end.

Comment: @j08691 There is no code, and I'm sorry if I used a word you don't like. Editing description to clarify.

Comment: @mtmurdock: j08691 meant the html and current css in the form of a fiddle

Comment: Also, you mention "tables" as in plural, that's what I meant by multiple

Comment: @fnostro I see your confusion. When I say 'tables' in the plural I mean different tables throughout the site which have the same style requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not part of CSS. [Shaun Inman suggested something like a parent selector](http://shauninman.com/archive/2008/05/05/css_qualified_selectors) that would allow parents to **inherit** from their children, but there are tons of issues with this methodology.

I would suggest, instead, that you try a javascript solution. You could search the table to see if it contains links, then add a class to the table in the case that they do. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Normal</th>
            <th>Align Me</th>
            <th>Normal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><a href="">...</a></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><a href="">...</a></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('td > a').each(function(){

    var $td = $(this).parent();
    $td.addClass('align-right');

    var $th = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index()).addClass('align-right');
});
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srZhL/) for you to check out.

Comment: This is clever. I think in the long run its probably not the best performing solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can only be applied to child or siblling elements. Children cannot tell their parents what to do.

Applying a class to the TD is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can not be done with CSS.
But in your special case, you can refer to the fact, that the column with the links is the last one in each row.

There is a special "pseudo-class" in CSS for this: last-child.

```
th:last-child { ... }
td:last-child { ... }
```

Comment: Yea I found that too. I was hoping for something that could apply to arbitrary columns, not just the last ones. last-child will work for my current project, but now I'm feeling academic about it and I'm hoping there's another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, but it only works when the actions are the last column in the table.

```
<table class="hasActions">
...
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
table.hasActions td:last-of-type, table.hasActions th:last-of-type {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Since this doens't work for arbitrary columns, I'll leave the question open for now.

Comment: so by arbitrary do you mean that it's not always the last column that has the actionable link?

Comment: Correct. Since actions mid table don't make sense design wise, consider instead a column which has formatted numbers, and I want them to appear different than other columns. (I recognize this is kind of odd, and I could just apply a class to each element, but I'm curious about the flexibility of CSS in this area).

Comment: If you have control over the rendering of the html and you can programmatically add classes at will, then just make any td that has an actionaable link be defined with a css class called, for instance, `.actionableLink` then it doesn't matter where the link lands in the table.  If you don't have that kind of access then you need to be able to look at all your tables and see if there is a way to clearly identity actionable links in terms of the css selectors

Comment: Yea I figured this might be the case. One can dream though.